# C# Linq List Compare and update lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists containing different types. One is a `string[]` and another is a `List<SelectListItem>`.

`SelectListItem` (it's in mvc):

```
public string Text {get;set;}
public string Value {get;set;}
public bool Selected {get;set;}
```

My `string[]` is just contains some text values.

What i'm trying to do  is, get whatever is in the `string[]`, then set `"Selected = true"` for whatever `Value` matches, and `"Selected = false"` for what doesnt match.

So lets say my `string[]` is:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

And my `List<SelectListItem>` is:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Testing", Value = "Test1", Selected = false },
new SelectListItem { Text = "Testing", Value = "Test4", Selected = true }
```

In the above `List<SelectListItem>`, i have one match. So what i'd like to do, is set Selected = true for that particular entry so that i end up with:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Testing", Value = "Test1", Selected = true },
new SelectListItem { Text = "Testing", Value = "Test4", Selected = false }
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: In the above scenario, what if Text4 had true, do you want it to set to false or leave the selected unchanged?

Comment: Set it to false. Sorry, i should have stated that in my question. I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var i in selectListItemList)
    i.Selected = stringArray.Contains(i.Value);
```

or using `List.ForEach`:

```
selectListItemList.ForEach(i => i.Selected = stringArray.Contains(i.Value));
```

Comment: Fine, this will set true to values present in list, but will also set other values to false even if there is true in them.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal "What i'm trying to do is, get whatever is in the string[], then set "Selected = true" for whatever Value matches, and "Selected = false" for what doesnt match." so I have done it this way. Otherwise your answer is the one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
list.ForEach(x => x.Selected = stringarray.Contains(x.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = SelectListItems.Where(p=>stringArray.Contains(p));;
foreach(var item in items)
    item.Selected=true;
```